# How to open a page inside a floating modal using Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

My plan is to open a modal when the user hovers a specific word on my page and inside that modal, I want to render a partial view of another web page.

This is what I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Add code review status to another page
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://mypage.com
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM_getResourceText
// @grant        GM_getResourceURL
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals jQuery, $ */

$("body").append ( '<div id="gmPopupContainer" style="display:none"><div id="gmPopupContent"></div></div>');

(function() {
  var bindToShowStatus = function() {
    jQuery("td#key").off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );

    jQuery("td#key").mouseenter(function(e) {
      var jira = jQuery(e.currentTarget);

      // Load gerrit page
      GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
          method:         "GET",
          url:            "https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/sushy/+/819309",
          headers: {
              "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
          },
          responseType:   "document",
          onload:         processDocumentResponse,
          onabort:        reportAJAX_Error,
          onerror:        reportAJAX_Error,
          ontimeout:      reportAJAX_Error
      } );
      $("#gmPopupContainer").show();
    }).mouseleave(function (e) {
      console.log("Out");
      $("#gmPopupContainer").hide();
    });
  };

  (new MutationObserver(check)).observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});

  function check(changes, observer) {
    if(document.querySelector('td#key')) {
      observer.disconnect();
      console.log("Loaded");
      bindToShowStatus();
    }
  }
})();

function processDocumentResponse (rspObj) {
    if (rspObj.status != 200 && rspObj.status != 304) {
        reportAJAX_Error (rspObj);
        return;
    }

    // NOW I need to get the page HTML and display inside the modal, but debugging the results of rspObj I see that the page I'm trying to access requires javascript and does not load correctly.

    //-- Add the info to a div and insert that div somewhere...
    'use strict';
    var my_div = document.getElementsByClassName("gmPopupContent")[0];
    my_div.innerHTML = 'Response' + my_div.innerHTML;
}

function reportAJAX_Error (rspObj) {
    console.error (`TM scrpt => Error ${rspObj.status}!  ${rspObj.statusText}`);
}

//--- CSS styles make it work...
GM_addStyle ( "                                                 \
    #gmPopupContainer {                                         \
        position:               fixed;                          \
        top:                    30%;                            \
        left:                   20%;                            \
        padding:                2em;                            \
        background:             white;                          \
        border:                 3px double black;               \
        border-radius:          1ex;                            \
        z-index:                777;                            \
    }                                                           \
    #gmPopupContainer button{                                   \
        cursor:                 pointer;                        \
        margin:                 1em 1em 0;                      \
        border:                 1px outset buttonface;          \
    }                                                           \
" );
```

The problem now is that I need to get the HTML and display inside the modal, but debugging the results of rspObj I see that the page I'm trying to access requires javascript and does not load correctly.

Any ideas on how to correctly render part of this page inside the modal?

Comment: If you want all of the functionality of the external page, wouldn't using an iframe be an easier option?

Comment: If I understand correctly that the other page uses javascript to render elements then you would need to run a headless browser on a server to parse the page content. Puppeteer for example

Comment: Thanks @DBS I will check if I can achieve that with iframe.

Comment: @charlietfl I would like to avoid the extra resource. Because of javascript being used to render the page, do you think headless browser is the only option I have or iframe can be used?

Comment: In an iframe you can only render the full page, not a partial. You can't access inside the frame to modify anything due to browser security restrictions

Comment: It may be easier to use the backtick (`\``) instead of quotes with backslashed to escape new lines in `GM_addStyle`.

Comment: @DBS I see that I cannot load the page on an iframe because 'X-Frame-Options' is set to 'deny'. Ideas?

Comment: If site you are trying to load in frame is blocking frames there is no iframe workaround. It is that sites prerogative to block others at will. Headless browser now really seems like only option